# Delete Temp Files inside Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat7

I have tomcat7 installed in a server. We have one application inside that. Now the application get crashed. When we try to login the session is not getting created. So i am thinking of deleting files inside `temp` under TOMCAT7 home folder.

Now my question,

1. Is it safe to delete temp folder?
2. Will there be any problems after deleting?

Here is the log `catalina.log`

```
`Mar 01, 2013 2:13:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.24 using APR version 1.4.6.
Mar 01, 2013 2:13:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Mar 01, 2013 2:13:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012)
Mar 01, 2013 2:13:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8081"]
Mar 01, 2013 2:13:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8081"]
 java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:423)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:649)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)

   Mar 01, 2013 2:13:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
   SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8081]]
   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8081]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:649)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
... 12 more
    Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:423)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
... 13 more

  Mar 01, 2013 2:13:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
  INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8010"]
  Mar 01, 2013 2:13:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
  SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8010"]
   java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:423)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:649)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)

    Mar 01, 2013 2:13:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
    SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8010]]
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component        [Connector[AJP/1.3-8010]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:649)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
... 12 more
    Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Socket bind failed: [730048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.  
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:423)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:610)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:429)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
... 13 more

   Mar 01, 2013 2:13:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
   INFO: Initialization processed in 2816 ms
   Mar 01, 2013 2:13:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
   INFO: Starting service Catalina
   Mar 01, 2013 2:13:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
   INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
   Mar 01, 2013 2:13:18 AM org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve open
   SEVERE: Failed to open access log file [C:\storefront\tomcat8081\logs\localhost_access_log.2013-03-01.txt]
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\storefront\tomcat8081\logs\localhost_access_log.2013-03-01.txt (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.open(AccessLogValve.java:1115)
at   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.startInternal(AccessLogValve.java:1222)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    Mar 01, 2013 2:13:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
    INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\storefront\tomcat8081\webapps       \storefrontAdmin.war
    Mar 01, 2013 2:13:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
    INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\storefront\tomcat8081\webapps  \storefrontAppServer.war
    Mar 01, 2013 2:13:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
    INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\storefront\tomcat8081\webapps\storefrontCatalog.war
    Mar 01, 2013 2:14:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
    INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\storefront\tomcat8081\webapps \storefrontCommerceTest.war
    Mar 01, 2013 2:14:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI:  is already defined
    Mar 01, 2013 2:14:05 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
    INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
```

Comment: When the app crashes, how can you still login (or access the services within the app)? Can you be more specific about how the app is crashing? See the logs under TOMCAT_HOME/logs. (May be, Catalina*.log) You may probably find out the problem from that.

Comment: yeah thanks, crashes means login page gets opening and the session is not getting created

Comment: Can you post the catalina logs? May be I can try to find out the problem.

Comment: @AmithKoujalgi, hi added can u pls check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like another app is using the port. If an app is already bound to a port, another app can't use/bind to the same port. Check which app is bound to that port.
Try this:

```
netstat -ntl | grep :8080
```

to see what process is using 8080 already.

If you want to change Tomcat's port, check the file **server.xml** in directory **TOMCAT_HOME\conf** the port address will be mentioned, if it is **8080**, try changing it to **8081** or whatever and start the server and hit localhost:8081 to check.

In **server.xml**, the code would look like:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Additionally, if you want to know which process is using the port, try this one:

```
netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:8080
```

THis will give you the process ID in the last column. Then from the task manager, find the process with that process ID and you'll know what process is using that port.

Comment: +1 Thanks, There is another application running at 8080 and that works fine. How can i change that?

Comment: You can change the port at which tomcat will run, as I mentioned in my answer above.